# Assigning several colors to nodes on the same network graph in R

Tags: r, sna

I think this is really basic, but we can't seem to find an answer to this question. We are building a network analysis graph, and would like to color each node based on attributes. We are able to do two colors, but need to do more than that. We are not using iGraph, although most searches we are finding give this example. Here is a look at our code for the different groups and colors:

```
#### Nodes Attributes ####################################################

nodeColors<-ifelse(nodeInfo$Section=="1","hotpink","dodgerblue")
#nodeColors<-(nodeInfo$Section)
## We can easily give two colors but we need four colors.
##########################################################################
##########################################################################
#### Visualisation    ####################################################

library(sna)
gplot(relations,gmode="graph",displaylabels=TRUE,vertex.col=nodeColors, mode = 
"fruchtermanreingold")
```

What we want to do is something like this:

We have 4 different groups assigned based on orientation groups:

```
nodeColors<-nodeInfo$Orientation=="1 2 3 4","red","blue","yellow","green")
```

Thoughts? What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> What are we doing wrong?

Noone can say, since you did not show a reproducible (=copy-paste-run'able) example of what you actually did.

However, I guess that `dplyr`'s `case_when` will make your life easier:

```
(x <- c(1:4, 1))
# [1] 1 2 3 4 1
dplyr::case_when(
  x==1~"red",
  x==2~"orange",
  x==3~"blue",
  TRUE~"lightgray"
)
# [1] "red"       "orange"    "blue"      "lightgray" "red"
```

You may need `install.packages("dplyr")` beforehand. `x` is `nodeInfo$Orientation` in your question. You can assign the result of `case_when` to your variable `nodeColors` using `<-`. See `?dplyr::case_when` for more info on that function.